# Having an array of javascript objects as an ajax call parameter, without jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send an array of JavaScript objects to my ASP.Net MVC controller **without using jQuery**. I have a simple array of JavaScript objects like this...

```
var data = [];

data.push(new person(1, "David"));
data.push(new person(2, "Karine"));
data.push(new person(2, "Annie"));
...etc

function person(_id, _name) {
    this.id = _id;
    this.name = _name;
}
```

...and I would like to have it as a parameter of an ajax call like this:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {                                                
                            if (i == 1) {
                                    alert(obj[i].name);}
                        }
                }
                else {
                    alert('There is an error');
                }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Home/AjaxTester?id=15&name=dave", true);                             
xmlhttp.send();
```

The way I found so far to pass parameters to an ajax call, which is `...Home/AjaxTester?id=15&name=dave`, works fine for basic types, but I can't find a way to do the same with more "complex" types. I'm open to new ways to parameterize my ajax call if anything better, or even a new way to make an ajax call, as long as it is pure JavaScript, no library, no framework, or whatever.

Here's my MVC controller...

```
public JsonResult AjaxTester(List<Person> _person)
{
    //Whatever Logic...

    return Json(_someObjects);
}
```

...and the class of the received parameter

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; } = 0;      
        public string name { get; set; } = "";

        public Person(int _id, string _name)
        {
            this.id = _id;
            this.name = _name;
        }
}
```

Comment: Complex types shouldn't be sent in the query string at all.

Comment: Then, where is that supposed to be set?

Comment: The message body, except for GET requests. 
 The spec says servers are supposed to ignore the body for GET requests.  If you're sending a complex object to a GET request, it probably shouldn't be a GET.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `FromUri` command before parameters, like this:

```
public JsonResult AjaxTester(FromUri List<Person> _person)
```

Comment: @DaveD The same way you have it in your client-side code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your http method from GET to POST.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/Home/AjaxTester?id=15&name=dave", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Make sure you add the setRequestHeader. If you are sending a json object then change the request header to the following:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

I would also recommend removing the query parameter and updating the controller to accept this type of object. You may also need to add the [FromBody] in next to that parameter.

And your controller should be updated similar to

```
public JsonResult AjaxTester([FromBody] List<Person> _person)
```

Comment: There isn't any benefit to setting the content type header if there isn't a message body.  OP is sending values in the query string.

Comment: We're almost there: I did as you say, my controller gets triggered ok, but "_person" always has a count of 0? There must be something wrong from what I did...I'll review what I did!

Comment: I've done my testing, but still, it's not working: Whatever I send through xhr.send(data) is always null on the server side, even strings don't work, though the controller is always triggered!

Comment: Did you verify that you are using the setRequestHeader? Also, try to JSON.stringiify(data)). I'll update my answer with that so its easier to see in the code view.

Comment: You may want to try testing without a list at first. Then once you get that working add the list back in